# Difference between MSE and variance

Tags: variance, mse

In statistics, sometimes we use mean sum of error, and sometimes variance. I just want to know what is the difference between mean sum of error and variance?

Comment: "MSE" stands for *Mean Squared Error*, not "mean *sum of* error."

Answer (score 4):

$MSE = {\rm variance} + {\rm bias}^2$.  As per gung, MSE is mean squared error.

Answer (score 2):

They measure two different things.

Variance measures the spread of a variable.  While MSE measures the deviation from a predictor.  MSE is usually associated with a function:

If you are trying to measure how well a function, say Y=mX+b, predicts Y then you would use MSE.  Note that here the MSE <> Variance.

I could guess the confusion mostly comes from when you have a target value in manufacturing.  Say you have a target value of 4 on a measurement.  MSE would take into account the mean's shift from the target as well as the variance.  So values of 2, 3, 4, 5 would yield MSE of  1.5 and variance of 1.3